# Listen to a range of UDP ports

Tags: c#, udp

I'm listening for when a game joins a server and I know the range of ports but unfortunately UDPClient's Receive functionality only listens to a specific port. Since the port it joins is random in the range, is there a good way to handle listening on a UDP port range?

This is from the games forum from their developers:
"Dota 2 uses the UDP protocol and communicates on ports 27015 through 28999 to our dedicated servers. By default, your client opens UDP port 27005 or your computer to connect to the game servers." - http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=15261

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with the sockets API.  You'll want to use a library that ties into the TCP/IP stack at a deeper level, for example `libpcap`.

Since you use C#, you'd be most interested in [pcap.NET, a .NET interface to WinPCap](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)

If you wanted to match the destination UDP port, you could use a filter of

```
udp[2:2] >= 9000 and udp[2:2] < 9100
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you should not be listening to a range of ports. Rather listen to one port but accept it from any IP address. You can achieve this by using:

```
IPAddress.Any
```

As the address argument to listen on. Then on the other end specify the destination port as the one your server is listening on.

For example to receive data from any client on port 11000:

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);
IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
byte[] receivedBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

Comment: So what would be an approach then if the game is connecting via a port range and I want to be aware of when it makes a connection? I'll edit my post to show what the game developers say.

Comment: I _guess_ they are using a range to load limit a particular server (i.e. they have different servers running on different ports) but the initial connection will be made to one port. So my answer remains.